# C# ReportViewer The source of the Report Definition has not been specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, rdlc, reportviewer

[image: Error]

Please help me to solve this problem

I have a C# project connected with the SQL server
I want to preview the report in this project but dot know why my code doesn't work

```
//ReportDataSource reportDataSource;
try
{
    // Set the processing mode for the ReportViewer to Remote  
    reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

    ServerReport serverReport = reportViewer1.ServerReport;

    // Get a reference to the default credentials  
    System.Net.ICredentials credentials =
        System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    // Get a reference to the report server credentials  
    ReportServerCredentials rsCredentials =
        serverReport.ReportServerCredentials;

    // Set the credentials for the server report  
    rsCredentials.NetworkCredentials = credentials;

    //this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Reports\Report1.rdlc";
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

    DataSet1 dataSet1 = new DataSet1();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    
    con.Open();
    sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT 
                                                    dbo.Sales.product_name, dbo.Sales.price_dollar, dbo.Sales.price_dinar, dbo.Sales.quantity, dbo.Sales.totoal_dollar, dbo.Sales.total_dinar
                                                    FROM   dbo.Customers INNER JOIN
                                                    dbo.SaleReport ON dbo.Customers.customer_id = dbo.SaleReport.customer_id INNER JOIN
                                                    dbo.Sales ON dbo.SaleReport.trans_no = dbo.Sales.trans_no
                                                    where Sales.trans_no = '" + 1 + "';", con);
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet1.Tables["Products"]);
    con.Close();

    ReportDataSource dsSalesOrder = new ReportDataSource();
    dsSalesOrder.Name = "DataSet1";
    dsSalesOrder.Value = dataSet1.Tables["Products"];

    //reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataSet1.Tables["Products"]);

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dsSalesOrder);
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = @"Report2.rdlc";
    reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
    reportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent;
    reportViewer1.ZoomPercent = 100;
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Repeating the same text in the question multiple times will get flagged as spam if you continue to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error said,

> The source of the report definition has not been specified

You need to specify the rdlc template file before you can add parameters or generate reports.

I think you just called the wrong method,
the line:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = @"Report2.rdlc";
```

Should actually be:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Report2.rdlc";
```